# Host a network behind another network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I'm not very good at this but I'll try to be as specific as I can.

**The situation:**
I'm getting my internet from my neighbour through wireless connection to my stationary PC.
I have some network devices that I want to access, but don't want to share on my neighbour's network.

I'd like (if even possible) to use internet connection from my stationary PC to give my own router internet access and the ability to host a private network (cabled from my stationary PC). Then comes the tricky part:
I'd like to host a different network from my router (different SSID and password). This is because of printers and network hard drives that i don't want on my neighbour's network.
I've tried to Google around but all i can find is ways to extend a network.

I don't have access to change settings on the main router (my neighbour's).

**So my question is:** Is it possible to achieve this and if so, what is the best way to do it? How do I need to set up my router?
Picture below illustrates the situation where ofc I want to connect my devices to "My wifi":

[image]

**Then bonusquestion:**
How do I access devices on my wifi from the stationary PC? Normally I would access it through the IP on that network (192.168.0.X) but that won't help as I'm connected to my neighbour's network and only sharing the internet for my own (not really connected to it).

**Also:** I'm not using my neighbours internet behind his back, he's fully aware that I'm using his internet as my only internet.

Thanks for any help, and if please explain like you would to a five year old and maybe I'll understand :)

Comment: Are you asking this http://superuser.com/questions/730889/can-i-hook-up-my-own-router-to-use-the-isprouter/730895#730895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set-up which Minde is trying to achieve is different from the one referred to by Dave Rook.

1) First, Minde wants to share a wifi connection between his desktop (I suppose this is what Minde means by stationary) and the router; no such thing in Dave Rook's reference;

2) second, he wants to be able to talk to all machines connected to his new wifi network from the desktop, *backwards* thru the router, so to speak.

The answer to this is:

1) Point 1 can be achieved in any OS: in Windows, it is called Internet Connection Sharing, ICS. A very good explanation can be found [here](http://www.countrymilewifi.com/how-to-share-computers-wifi-with-ethernet-devices.aspx), it is easy to follow.

2) Point 2 is trickier. You see, you are already using your wifi card to connect to your neighbour's network, so, in order to connect to your new wifi network, you will need either another wifi card, or the ability to build a *virtual interface* on the same, single wifi card you already have. You can do that in Windows, by means of the [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013). Or, you may just decide it is easier to buy a second USB wifi card, and use that one instead.

In any case, you must make sure that the traffic is correctly routed. In other words, you must make sure that this new wifi interface, through which you are connect to your own new wifi network, is used only to reach your local network, not the Internet in general.

You do that by making sure that your default gateway (in your friend's home) is 192.168.1.1, while your home network is 192.168.0.07/24. The command

```
route print
```

displays the routing table. The command

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

tells your pc to use 192.168.1.1 as the default gateway, and the command

```
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

does so in a permanent (-p!) way. Just in case, the command

```
route del 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1
```

relieves 192.168.0.1 from its position as default gateway.

I am assuming your desktop has Windows installed. In Unix/Linux, even more complicated setups are possible, ask if you need help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I'm using Windows. What you're saying in point 1 is allready done, but I'm unsure what settings is needed on my router. I've tested the connection behind my stationary by pluging another PC directly with cable (this works fine), but my router does not get acces to the internet.
Also, I do have two network cards: The wifi card is added recently and the main card that is built in the motherboard.

Comment: @Minde Have you tried plugging the 2nd pc into the router (i.e., with the cable) and seeing whether you get a connection? If the answer is **no**, have you made sure that the two networks (your firend's and yours) are different? In other words, if your friend has 192.168.1.0/24, your router *cannot* use the same, it must absolutely be different, or it will not work.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a bunch. I didn't know that the routers had to have a different default gateway (Like I said I'm not good at this :P), but it works fine now.